# Sending MMS through Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

I Need your guidance in sending MMS through exactTarget mobile connect.I studied various documentation in exactTarget but there is no clear steps for implementing MMS.I came across Media share template but i dont find any such templates in my ET mobile Connect account.It will be very helpful if some one guides me in this.

Comment: @Kelly J Andrews can u guys help??

Answer (score 1):

Manoj,  See the Message Contact Send API with the optional Content URL.

https://code.exacttarget.com/api/messagecontact-send

here's an example API call:

```
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/MzA6Nzg6MA/send?access_token=...
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "mobileNumbers": [
    "13175551212"
    ],
    "Subscribe": false,
    "Resubscribe": false,
    "Override": true,
    "messageText": "Welcome to Code@",
    "ContentURL" : "http://image.exct.net/lib/fe6d15707662057c7411/m/1/dj_CC_AUS.jpg"
}
```

I would suggest looking at the getting started guide to setup your MMS message and message ID:

https://code.exacttarget.com/content/mobileconnect-getting-started-0

```
David Galante
MobileConnect Product Manager
@davidgalante
```

Comment: thank you for your response .Actually im new to this exact target have little bit knowledge about SMS and Email.But no idea about MMS ...Actually for MMS where do we upload the content like video,img.....